# Linux: su error when run as root

Tags: su

why following command gives an error exit code, when run as root (tested under SLES11, RedHat 5.1):

```
srl-suse11-test:/tmp # su - user1 -c 'echo hallo'
srl-suse11-test:/tmp # echo $?
1
```

Thank in advance

Comment: Found the answer: user1 is a system account with shell /bin/false. use  `su - user1 -c 'echo hallo' -m` works

Comment: `echo$? gives the value 1 becasue 

echo$? means ,the exit status of the last command executed.`

Comment: @vkulkarni exactly, but 1 means failure. EXIT_SUCCESS is 0. Anyway, judging by first comment, reason is already found.